# Is chrome://flags/#enable-filesystem-in-incognito the only way to detect InCognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

[As announced in the press](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome%3A%2F%2Fflags%2F%23enable-filesystem-in-incognito%20detection&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A4%2F20%2F2019%2Ccd_max%3A), Chrome v74 finally introduced a way to bypass websites which detect InCognito mode.
Funny enough, none of the news sites actually bothered to check if it really does what it's supposed to do.

<del>However, I've tried it (by enabling chrome://flags/#enable-filesystem-in-incognito) in multiple sites and they still detected the mode.</del>

<del>Even [this short JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27805491/4829915) detected it, and it even specifically checks for filesystem, not anything else.</del>

**Update:** As of Chrome v75 (and simply by default since Chrome v76!), the only site I found that still detects this mode is Netflix. Does it mean sites like Netflix rely on other methods to detect InCognito mode? I read elsewhere it might simply be about running a DRM protected player that technically can't run in InCognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, you also have to disable web security (same origin policy etc.) to get Chrome to enable the filesystem in incognito mode.

Something like the below.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/temp"

Reference (from that same thread): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909367/can-you-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-a-script#comment99592904_27805491

Comment: This is dangerous, irresponsible advice. Do not run Chrome with `--disable-web-security`.

Comment: You can create a separate shortcut for your Washington Post incognito browsing.  I'm not recommending it for general use, but since the current feature is clearly locked behind --disable-web-security, if you want the feature you have no other option.

Comment: I've just added a comment that Chrome v75 fixed the original question, so this answer may not be needed anymore. The question now is how come some specific sites still bypass it.